# get selected value from second spinner on the basis of selected value of first spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to select value from second spinner on the basis of value selected in first spinner.For example my first spinner displays country name and second spinner displays city name of that respective country.The problem is that second spinner is always taking first value as selected.Example-first spinner is country name-India,pakistan,china and second spinner is cities name,so if i select india and my spinner is-delhi,up,punjab then it always get selected value as delhi always.When I change the selected value even the function onItemSelected is not calling again.Code for the same is-

```
public class LaunchCampaign1 extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener,OnClickListener
{
    String[] countryStr = {"Select", "India", "Pakistan", "China"};
    String[] states_india = {"Select", "Delhi", "UP", "Bihar"};
    String[] states_china = { "Select","Shanghai", "Beijing", "Nanjing"};
    String[] states_pak = { "Select","Lahor", "Islamabaad", "Punjab"};
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_campaign);
country=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);

        country.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        ArrayAdapter <String> c = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,countryStr);
        c.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        country.setAdapter(c);

        city=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCity);
        city.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        city.setEnabled(false);
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) 
    {
        if(arg0.equals(country))
        {
            city.setEnabled(true);
            if(country.getSelectedItem().equals("India"))
            {
                ArrayAdapter <String> s1 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_india);
                s1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                city.setAdapter(s1);
                /*city.setSelection(position);
                Log.e("pos",""+position);
                String cityStr = (String) city.getSelectedItem();*/
                String cityStr=(String) city.getSelectedItem();
                Log.e("city",cityStr);
             }
             else  if(country.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan"))
             {
                 ArrayAdapter <String> s2 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_pak);
                 s2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 city.setAdapter(s2);
             }
             else  if(country.getSelectedItem().equals("China"))
             {
                 ArrayAdapter <String> s3 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_china);
                 s3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 city.setAdapter(s3);
             }
        }
   } 
    }
```

Comment: By default first value will be selected for both of your _Spinners_. So on onCreate() method you have to load your second spinner according to your first value of your first Spinner.

Comment: how can i change it-@Piyush Gupta

Comment: For display `Select` as a default text use `prompt` for it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution of my problem.I just need to implement the onItemSelectListener for second spinner also.Now the updated code is-

```
public class LaunchCampaign1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnItemSelectedListener
{
String[] countryStr = {"Select", "India", "Pakistan", "China"};
    String[] states_india = {"Select", "Delhi", "UP", "Bihar"};
    String[] states_china = { "Select","Shanghai", "Beijing", "Nanjing"};
    String[] states_pak = { "Select","Lahor", "Islamabaad", "Punjab"};
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_campaign);
country=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);

        country.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        ArrayAdapter <String> c = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,countryStr);
        c.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        country.setAdapter(c);

        city=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCity);
        city.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        city.setEnabled(false);
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
    {
        switch(parent.getId())
        {
            case R.id.spinnerCountry: 
                city.setEnabled(true);
                if(country.getSelectedItem().equals("India"))
                {
                    ArrayAdapter <String> s1 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_india);
                    s1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    city.setAdapter(s1);
                }
                else  if(country.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan"))
                {
                    ArrayAdapter <String> s2 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_pak);
                    s2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    city.setAdapter(s2);
                }
                else  if(country.getSelectedItem().equals("China"))
                {
                    ArrayAdapter <String> s3 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_china);
                    s3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    city.setAdapter(s3);
                }
            break;

            case R.id.spinnerCity:
                String cityStr1=city.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.e("city1",cityStr1);
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I was looking for this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Data1Activity extends Activity {
String[] countryStr = { "India",  "China","Pakistan"};
String[] states_india = { "Delhi", "UP", "Bihar"};
String[] states_china = { "Shanghai", "Beijing", "Nanjing"};
String[] states_pak = { "Lahor", "Islamabaad", "Punjab"};
Spinner country,city;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptercountry;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptercity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    country= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    city = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adaptercountry = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countryStr);
    country.setAdapter(adaptercountry);

    country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if(position==0)
            {
                adaptercity = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,states_india);
            }
            else
                if(position==1)
                {
                    adaptercity = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,states_china);
                }
                else
                    if(position==2)
                    {
                        adaptercity = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,states_pak);
                    }

            city.setAdapter(adaptercity);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

  }

}
```